# mailchimp email not displaying correctly in gmail

Tags: html, image, button, gmail, mailchimp

I created a template in mailchimp using HTML. 
I tried to sent a test email but it does not display the exact contents in gmail.
The buttons is at the bottom of the template when you are viewing it in gmail.
May I know what did I do wrong?

This is my code:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 700px;
}

.container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.container .bt {
  position: absolute;
  top: 760px;
  left: 434px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #721213;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container .bt2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1110px;
  left: 212px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #721213;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container .bt3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1540px;
  left: 440px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #721213;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/b83344d645769870e9125f7a2/images/0463afae-1bff-42ac-b887-b721e137a04b.png" alt="Snow" style="width:100%">
  <a href="https://www.orochinajewelry.com/product-tag/12-12/" class="bt">SHOP NOW</a>
  <a href="https://www.orochinajewelry.com/product-category/daily-wear/" class="bt2">SHOP NOW</a>
  <a href="https://www.orochinajewelry.com/product-category/made-for-you/" class="bt3">SHOP NOW</a>
</div>
```

Please see screenshot: 
[image]

Comment: Can you please provide your code of mailchimp? So we can get better vision.

Comment: Did you use table format for email template?

Comment: that's the only code.

I didn't use table format

Answer (score 0):

Position absolute gets stripped by many email clients including Gmail.

You can use `inline-block` and `margin-top` and `margin-left` instead.

See updated snippet, and read more in [this blog](https://www.gorebel.com/blog/absolute-positioning-in-email).

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 700px;
}

.container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.container .bt {
  display:inline-block
  margin-top: 760px;
  margin-left: 434px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #721213;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container .bt2 {
  display:inline-block;
  margin-top: 1110px;
  margin-left: 212px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #721213;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container .bt3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1540px;
  left: 440px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #721213;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/b83344d645769870e9125f7a2/images/0463afae-1bff-42ac-b887-b721e137a04b.png" alt="Snow" style="width:100%">
  <a href="https://www.orochinajewelry.com/product-tag/12-12/" class="bt">SHOP NOW</a>
  <a href="https://www.orochinajewelry.com/product-category/daily-wear/" class="bt2">SHOP NOW</a>
  <a href="https://www.orochinajewelry.com/product-category/made-for-you/" class="bt3">SHOP NOW</a>
</div>
```